# how to eval / constantize a string to a method, then pass arguments to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Given:

```
s = "foo_bar_path"
```

How can I eval or constantize s, and pass arguments to it, such as my final result would be the equivalent of:

```
foo_bar_path(@myvar, @foobar)
```

I was trying `eval(s).send` but that doesn't seem to work. And constantize seems to only work on Classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would just use the [`send` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) (or [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) depending on your needs) on the appropriate object:

```
some_object.send(s, @myvar, @foobar)
```

or if you want to call a method on yourself:

```
self.send(s, @myvar, @foobar)
```

The documentation says "symbol" but `send` is just as happy to get the method name in a string.

Comment: Here is another example of what I am trying to do: given s = "puts", I want to be able to 'methodize' s, and pass it an argument, so something like eval(s) "hello world" would yield the equivalent output of "hello world", ie, it would execute the expression puts "hello world".

Comment: @user970193: Possibly the current object so maybe `send(s, @mybar, @foobar)`. We're a bit short on context here.

Comment: s = "puts"; send(s, "hello world") does exactly what I want! Thanks mu!

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me come up with `ApplicationRecord.descendants.collect {|model| [model.name, model.name.constantize.send(:count)]}`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go about this sort of this sort of thing (better for OpenStruct):

```
#for more in this domain, see the Ruby core API for the Object class
class Demo
  def initialize(n)
    @iv = n
  end
  def hello()
    "Hello, @iv = #{@iv}"
  end
end

k = Demo.new(99)
m = k.method(:hello)
m.call   #=> "Hello, @iv = 99"
```